# Sorting objects by multiple properties

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell for sorting objects representing application verions

```
$versionsObjects = @{
    Major = 3
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
},
@{
    Major = 3
    Minor = 5
    Bugfix = 1
},
@{
    Major = 1
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
},
@{
    Major = 4
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
}

$sortedVersions = ($versionsObjects | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression="Major"; Descending=$true}, @{Expression="Minor" ;Descending=$true}, @{Expression="Bugfix"; Descending=$true})
$sortedVersions | %{echo ( "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $_.Major, $_.Minor, $_.Bugfix)}
```

The output is in the same order as input:

```
3.2.1
3.5.1
1.2.1
4.2.1
```

But it should be

```
4.2.1
3.5.1
3.2.1
1.2.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are at least in powershell v3.0 you can do it like this:

```
$versionsObjects = [ordered]@{
    Major = 3
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
},
[ordered]@{
    Major = 3
    Minor = 5
    Bugfix = 1
},
[ordered]@{
    Major = 1
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
},
[ordered]@{
    Major = 4
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
}

$versionsObjects | % { $_.values  -join '.' } | sort -Descending {[version]$_ }
```

or for all version:

```
$versionsObjects = @{
    Major = 3
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
},
@{
    Major = 3
    Minor = 5
    Bugfix = 1
},
@{
    Major = 1
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
},
@{
    Major = 4
    Minor = 2
    Bugfix = 1
}

$versionsObjects | % { $_.Major,$_.Minor,$_.bugfix  -join '.' } | sort -Descending {[version]$_ }
```

Comment: That would use string based comparison, wouldn't it? This can lead to troubles if versions are not single digit.

Comment: @gisek No string comparison.. .net object `[version]` comparison! Try it ;)

Comment: you are comparing strings. so version 9 would be higher than version 10

Comment: This is awesome. didn't know about [Ordered], I always did the hacky join!

Answer (score 12):

Your expressions aren't quite right. Try this for the Sort-Object part:

```
Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={$_.Major}; Descending=$true}, @{Expression={$_.Minor} ;Descending=$true}, @{Expression={$_.Bugfix}; Descending=$true})
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to make it work with a hashtable , but I was successful when I sorted with a custom PSObject instead. Maybe it'll be helpful?

```
$versionsObjects = @()

$versionsObjects += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Major = 3; Minor = 2 ; Bugfix = 1}
$versionsObjects += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Major = 3; Minor = 5 ; Bugfix = 1}
$versionsObjects += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Major = 1; Minor = 2 ; Bugfix = 1}
$versionsObjects += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Major = 4; Minor = 2 ; Bugfix = 1}


$versionsObjects |

Sort-Object -Property Major,Minor,Bugfix -Descending |

ForEach-Object -Process {

echo ( "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $_.Major, $_.Minor, $_.Bugfix)

                    }
```